# How to increment DateTime? nullabe value in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

After Looking at so many similar questions I'm unable to find answer to this particular situation where I want to increment `DateTime?` nullable value.

```
DateTime? startDate= new DateTime();
startDate = log.StartDate;
```

in a loop I want this startDate to be incremented by 1. But as it is a nullable I am not allowed to do so. Can someone please help?

Comment: What is `new Nullable<DateTime>()` + one day?

Comment: Log is a WorkLog class object of JIRA and i m trying to create a recurring task utility in which duration can be entered and worklogs for that duration will be updated on dates. for this i want a loop which will loop through days and will add a day to startDate for the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime? startDate = new DateTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    startDate = startDate.Value.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: You have to assign the returned `DateTime` to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda like this?

```
DateTime? startDate= DateTime.UtcNow;
for(int i = 0;  i < 5; i++)
{               
    DateTime? newStartDate = startDate.Value.AddDays(i);
    Console.WriteLine(newStartDate.Value);
}
```

[See it working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oAK6vF)